# Fetch dependencies from specific URL

Tags: gradle

How can I fetch dependencies from a specific URL, i.e. I would like do something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'http://rforge.net/Rserve/files/RserveEngine.jar'
    compile 'http://rforge.net/Rserve/files/REngine.jar'
}
```

is this even possible or do I have to download the jars in a separate task and add them using

```
compile files('....')
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is the way to go:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    ivy {
        url 'http://rforge.net/Rserve/files/'
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}

configurations{
    rserve
}

dependencies {
    rserve name: 'RserveEngine'
    rserve name: 'REngine'
}

task fetchRserve(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.rserve
    into "$buildDir/rserve"
}
```

You can experiment with ivy layout to introduce modules, versions, extensions. [Here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) the docs can be found.